# Android: Changing image inside for loop without locking UI

Tags: android

This is my code below.

```
for(int k=1 ; k<=1000; k++)
{
    if((k%2)==0)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbie2);
    else
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbie3);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    } 
}
```

I want swap two images every 1 second without locking UI.
How can I do it in android please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do it in a separate thread by this way:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int k=1 ; k<=1000; k++)
            {
                if((k%2)==0)
                    i.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbie2);
                        }
                    });

                else
                    i.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.barbie3);
                        }
                    });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    } 
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

if possible, define your image `i` as `final`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the advice from its javadoc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

This does ***Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup***. If that's a concern, consider using `setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)` or `setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` and `BitmapFactory` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).